# Correct Proof Using Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Problem:** If $x>0$, show

$$|(1+x)^{1/3}-(1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{9})|\leq\frac{5x^3}{81}.$$

I know there are different ways to write Taylor's Theorem, but I'm just going to use one. Does this proof look correct?

Let $P_2(x,0)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2=1+\frac{1}{3}x-\frac{1}{9}x^2$ be the second degree Taylor Polynomial for $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/3}$. Where $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}(1+x)^{-2/3},\text{ and } f''(x)=-\frac{2}{9}(1+x)^{-5/3}$. So, $f'(0)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $f''(0)=-\frac{2}{9}$. By Taylor's Theorem, $|f(x)-P_2(x,0)|=|\frac{f^{(3)}(c)}{3!}||x^3|$ for $c\in (0,x)$. However, $\frac{f^{(3)}(c)}{3!}||x^3|=\frac{5}{81}(1+c)^{-8/3}|x^3|$. For $c>0$ the right hand side becomes less than $\frac{5}{81}$. So, to keep this as large as possible $c=0$, therefore, it must be true that:

$$|f(x)-P_2(x,0)|=|(1+x)^{1/3}-(1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{9})|\leq\frac{5x^3}{81}.\text{ $\square$}$$

Comment: Where does the $-$ sign come from in $f'$?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I'm not sure which $-$ sign you're referring to? The only negative is with $f''$ which comes just pops out from the derivative of $f'$

Comment: I'm referring to the $-$ sign which shouldn't be here.

Comment: $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are both wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see what you two are saying, complete typo.

Comment: What about $8/5$?

Comment: The sentence "For the largest remainder, =0..." isn't clear to me. $c$ is fixed. Just show that this quantity that depends on $c$ is less than $1$.

Comment: I believe I understand what you're saying. I fixed it.